# Error: Cloning a bare git repository

Tags: git, dropbox, git-bare

I tried to make a new bare git repository but I get this error:

```
Max:Git-Projekte max$ git clone --bare . ~/Dropbox/Git-Projekte/Mainpage.git
Cloning into bare repository '/Users/max/Dropbox/Git-Projekte/Mainpage'...
fatal: failed to open '/Users/max/Dropbox/Git-Projekte/./objects': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you are using the command the right way:

Man for git-clone says:

"Clones a repository into a newly created directory"

command is:

```
git clone [--template=<template_directory>]
      [-l] [-s] [--no-hardlinks] [-q] [-n] [--bare] [--mirror]
      [-o <name>] [-b <name>] [-u <upload-pack>] [--reference <repository>]
      [--depth <depth>] [--recursive] [--] <repository> [<directory>]
```

So maybe you should:

```
git clone --bare ~/Dropbox/Git-Projekte/Mainpage.git .
```

?

Comment: hm that does not work, i think the problem is that the command should ignore the repository and just make a bare one. But this doesn't work